# What's your naming convention for helper functions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, naming-conventions

In functional programming, it's often important to optimize any "looping" code to be tail recursive. Tail recursive algorithms are usually split between two functions, however - one which sets up the base case, and another that implements the actual loop. A good (albeit academic) example would be the reverse function.

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = reverse_helper []

reverse_helper :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
reverse_helper result [] = result
reverse_helper result (x:xs) = reverse_helper (x:result) xs
```

"reverse_helper" isn't really a good, descriptive name. However, "reverse_recursive_part" is just awkward.

What naming convention would you use for helper functions like this?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm working on a Haskell project right now, which inspired this question. I could have given a Python/Java example I suppose, although such helper functions aren't as useful in imperative languages.

Comment: `loop`, `foo`, `go`, or just `g`. of course make it internal, and not accessible globally like the one you show. if it must be global, then `yourfunctionsname_aux`. as for the primed names, personally, I dislike them very very much. we name things to distinguish between them, and `longfunctionname'` is not very distinguishable from its non-primed counterpart, to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to add "_recurse" to the end. So "reverse_recurse". Not sure where I got that from. I like leaving the base case function simple as you have in your example. It tends to be the "public" function and the fact that it uses a helper function to perform the iteration is irrelevant to the caller. In javascript I sometimes go so far as to hide the iterative function via a closure, to make it really clear it is not to be called directly.

Answer (score 24):

You can call the helper function anything you want, and it won't matter as long as you don't put the helper function in the "global" namespace. Simply adding a "prime" seems a common practice. :) E.g., in Haskell,

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = reverse' []
    where reverse' :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
          reverse' result [] = result
          reverse' result (x:xs) = reverse' (x:result) xs
```

Answer (score 8):

I agree with ShreevatsaR, if you don't make the helper function top-level (or worse, put it in the export list), than it doesn't matter what its name is.
I tend to call helper functions `f` and `g`.

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = f []
  where
    f ys []     = xs
    f ys (x:xs) = f (x:ys) xs
```

I just use this naming scheme for small functions (otherwise I don't know what the `f` refers to). Then again, why would you ever write big functions?

However, if you do want to export your 'helper' function because it might be useful to others, I would call it:

```
reverseAccumulator
```

Like Haskell's `zip` and `zipWith`.
But I wouldn't call those 'helper' functions, `zipWith` is just a generic function and `zip` is the default implementation (probably the one thats used the most).

Comment: I like the use of prime (rev -> rev'= as ShreevatsaR suggest, but I think this should be the accepted answer due to it's generality and because it relates to conventions in the libraries.

Answer (score 7):

I always use do_, like "do_compute" with "compute". I find it quite descriptive as it is effectively the part of the function that performs the action, whereas the "compute" that gets called needs to have a simple descriptive name for the outside world.

Answer (score 4):

I use `aux` or `foo_aux` (for main function `foo`),  and nest the definition so it's not externally visible.

Answer (score 3):

I also agree with ShreevatsaR, in this example I would make the helper a private function.

For other cases where I need helper functions to be visible in the whole module, but not exported, I tend to prefix functions with '_'.  Sure, there is the explicit exports statement but during development I tend to export all functions to ease interactive exploration, e.g. in ghci.  Later on I add the list of exported functions and the underbar makes it easy to remember whether I intended a function to be local or not.

Answer (score 1):

setup and execute

example:

```
function whateverSetup() { ... }
function whateverExecute() { ... }
```

Comment: whateverSetup is a horrible name if the function is public.

Comment: @[Cybis]: It should be implied that you replace "whatever" with an appropriate descriptive term, e.g. WidgetSetup, WidgetExecute, etc.

Comment: Steven: I think his point was that "Setup" is not a nice suffix for exported functions.